# Entity Framework core data migrations and tables created outside of EF

Tags: entity-framework-core

I create a table in my database that contains master data imported from an external source.

I now need to map this to a class and use it as a navigation property on other classes in my model.

How?!

The only way I've found is to set the `Table` attribute on the class and then in the migration comment out the table create/drop commands -- which seems rather unsatisfactory.

Surely there must be a proper way of mapping a POCO to an existing table? How?

Edit:

```
CRAETE TABLE Foo (Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

```
[Table("Foo")
public class Foo 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Running this command:

```
Add-Migration Foo
```

results in this migration class being created:

```
public partial class Foo: Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Foo",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Foo", x => x.Id);
            });
    }
}
```

But the migration should not run and create the table because it already exists.

Comment: Your question is very broad and a lot of information is missing. Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Then show the problem or issue you have with that code.

Comment: Your approach is the recommended approach, if you must use migrations. Remember that the migration classes are scaffolded code.